# Intercambiar 2 imágenes al clickear en ellas

Tags: javascript, onclick

Éste es mi código. Necesito que al clickear en una primera imagen y luego en una segunda, las intercambie. Consigo que me lea el `src` de las imágenes, pero no sé como intercambiarlos.
Gracias

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

// función que se ejecute al darle clic a cada una de las imágenes
// pasamos como atributo a la función la palabra reservada this que hace referencia al propio elemento

function cambiar(imagen) {

    var anterior = "";
    var aux = "";

    if(anterior != ""){
        aux = anterior;
        anterior = imagen.src;  //obtenemos la ruta de la imagen con imagen.src
    }else{
        anterior = imagen.src;
    }

    console.log("Anterior: " + anterior);
    console.log("Auxiliar: " + aux);

    //obtener el atributo src de la imagen que has clicado. una vez obtengas la ruta de la imagen en la que acabas de hacer clic, se la puedes asignar a la imagen 2    
} 

</script>

<body>

    <img id="myImage" src=".\images_ex2\01.jpg" alt="arte abstracto" onclick="cambiar(this)" name="canvi">  
    <img id="myImage" src=".\images_ex2\02.jpg" alt="arte abstracto" onclick="cambiar(this)" name="canvi">  
    <img id="myImage" src=".\images_ex2\03.jpg" alt="arte abstracto" onclick="cambiar(this)" name="canvi">  

</body>
```

Comment: lo mejor seria tener las imagenes en array y mostrarlas en ese orden del array , al seleccionar las 2 moves los indices del array y recargas las imagenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto te funcionara:

```
<script> 
var img = {src:"", id:""};

function cambiar(imagen) {
    if(img.src=="" && img.id==""){
        img.src=imagen.src;
        img.id=imagen.id;
    }
    else{ 
        var aux = imagen.src;

        document.getElementById(imagen.id).src = img.src;
        document.getElementById(img.id).src = aux;

        img.src = ""; img.id="";
    }
} 
</script>
```

Procura que los id de las imagenes sean distintos

```
<body>

<img id="myImage1" src=".\images_ex2\01.jpg" alt="arte abstracto" onclick="cambiar(this)" name="canvi">  
<img id="myImage2" src=".\images_ex2\02.jpg" alt="arte abstracto" onclick="cambiar(this)" name="canvi">  
<img id="myImage3" src=".\images_ex2\03.jpg" alt="arte abstracto" onclick="cambiar(this)" name="canvi">  

</body>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda @Cris. Pero el código me da un error en el if de la function.  "Invalid left-hand side in assignment".

Comment: Oh. Por fin!   He colocado paréntesis entre las dos condiciones y  FUNCIONA!!  `  if( (img.src == "") && ( img.id == "" ) )`  Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo he hecho con `jQuery` y me funciona. Como se indica en la respuesta anterior, los `id` deben ser diferentes.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var clickedimages = {};

    $('#images').on('click', 'img', function () {

        let $clicked = $(this);
        $clicked.addClass('seleccionada');
        let size = parseInt(Object.keys(clickedimages).length);

        switch (size) {
            case 0:                
                let entryOne = getData($clicked);
                clickedimages[size] = entryOne;
                break;

            case 1:
                let entryTwo = getData($clicked);
                clickedimages[size] = entryTwo;
                changeImageSrc(clickedimages);
                Object.keys(clickedimages).forEach((x) => {
                    delete clickedimages[x];
                });
                $('#images').find('.seleccionada').each(function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('seleccionada')                
                });
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    });
});

function changeImageSrc(images) {

    let index = 0;

    Object.keys(images).forEach((element) => {
        let index = parseInt(element);
        if (index === 0) {
            $('#images').find('#' + images[index]['id']).attr('src', images[index + 1]['src']);
            index++;
        } else {
            $('#images').find('#' + images[index]['id']).attr('src', images[index - 1]['src']);
        }
    });
}

function getData($element) {
    return {
        'id': $element.attr('id'),
        'src': $element.attr('src')
    };
}
```

```css
.seleccionada{
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* msie */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="images">
        <div>
            <img id="imagen1" src="./images/imagen1.jpeg" alt="arte abstracto" name="canvi">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="imagen2" src="./images/imagen2.jpeg" alt="arte abstracto" name="canvi">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="imagen3" src="./images/imagen3.jpeg" alt="arte abstracto" name="canvi">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Victor Herasme por tu completa respuesta, pero el código, aunque funciona, no acaba de hacer lo que necesito. Las imágenes no se intercanvian de posición. Solo ocupan el lugar de la imagen1 al clicar sobre alguna de las otras.

Comment: Puedes dar más detalles? A lo mejor puedo ayudarte

Comment: Perdona Victor.  Me quedó el comentario a medias.   Podrías, por favor indicarme como modificar el código para que al clicar sobre una imagen, ésta quede seleccionada y al hacer clic en cualquiera de las restantes, ambas intercambien posiciones.    Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pruebalo con las modificaciones que he hecho. Modifica el estilo de la clase `.seleccionada` según tus preferencias